# IF function in Excel not returning correct value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can you help me with this formula?

[image]

It is returning 0 value despite me wanting it to return the 1000 from C6

[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with the Formula,, if possible better share the WB on cloud and let us examine the real data & the formula too.

Comment: **Continue**, if `C6 is 1000` then the `Yes` should be `E9`,,  count the ROW from C6,,, check the cell references in the formula !!

Comment: Please also check whether there is merged  cells and hidden column. If the text (Yes) is not aligned to right, the text should be automatically left aligned.

Comment: Maybe there is an extra 'space' in the C10 cell..

Answer (score 1):

The provided information makes it look like the value "Yes" is in column D (and so `Emily`'s comment about hidden columns!) and so the formula would likely fail as the hint of graphic makes it clear the cell in the next column is not "Yes".

`Emily`'s other point, about merged cells, could also be at work here as a right-aligned "Yes" in column D of merged columns D & E could be thought of by someone new to merged cells as being in column E since it looks like it must be column E. But is would be in D10, not E10, and E10 would actually be blank, something done by the merging process, so a `FALSE` would be returned.

The formula is returning a `0` because it is evaluating as `FALSE`:  not because the C6 cell has a numerical value of `0` because to this formula it doesn't. Firstly, the apparent number formatting (second PNG) is easily achieved by `$* #,##0.00`  and similar versions, the key being the `$*`  at its start, so the alignment of the number is not likely evidence of the value seen being formatted as text. And in any case, even a Text formatting would still allow a return as the simple formula has no issue returning text instead of a number:  in other words, it would NOT return a `0` simply because the value found was formatted as text.

Honestly, it seems very likely that there are no merged cells or hidden columns, but simply the "Yes" is actually **in column D**, as it would look in the PNG's, and so the value to its right is E10 and since that clearly does not look like a "Yes" the formula returns `FALSE` quite correctly. Second most likely seems like it would be `Emily`'s thought about merged cells combined with a mistake somewhat natural for a new user of merged cells.